# Is the following a sufficient condition to conclude that an algebraic plane curve is not closed?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, plane-curves

Suppose some algebraic curve is given by $\{F=0\}$, $F(X,Y)\in \mathbb{R}[X,Y]$. I am wondering whether we can use the existence of a solution of $F = 0$ when viewed as an element of $(\mathbb{R}[X])[Y]$ to determine whether or not $\{F=0\}$ is not closed. (When I say closed I do not mean in the topological sense, but rather that the curve 'ends at the same point it starts')

Specifically, since $F\in \mathbb{R}[X,Y]$, and  $\mathbb{R}[X,Y] \simeq (\mathbb{R}[X])[Y]$, $F$ may be viewed as a polynomial over the indeterminate $Y$, with coefficients that are polynomials over $X$. Suppose I identify $F\in \mathbb{R}[X,Y]$ with $\bar{F} \in (\mathbb{R}[X])[Y]$ (in the obvious way). I think that if $\bar{F}(a(x)) = 0$ for any polynomial $a(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$, then $\{F=0\}$ is not closed.

My justification for this is that $$\{F=0\} = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: F(x,y) = 0\}$$ But if $\bar{F}(a_0(x)) = 0 \in \mathbb{R}[X]$, then for every real number $x$, the tuple $(x,(a_0(x))\in \{F=0\}$ since $\bar{F}(a_0(x))$ is the zero polynomial. But this means that the curve must extend off in the "x-axis" to infinity as the curve is defined "for every point $x$".

Is this reasoning correct? I am not sure if this is meant to be trivial, or if I am missing something and the statement is completely wrong.

Comment: $F=0$ is always closed: it's the preimage of the closed set $\{0\}\in\Bbb R$ under the continuous map $F$. What do you mean?

Comment: @KReiser I think maybe my terminology is wrong, I (think) I don't mean closed in the topological sense. For example I would call an ellipse closed, but not a line. Perhaps it would be better to say not homeomorphic to the unit circle, but I am again unsure if there is a problem with this phrasing.

Comment: No, the terminology is correct, I just forgot about that meaning. Maybe a word about what you mean at the end of the first paragraph could help? (Btw, homeomorphic to the unit circle isn't quite right - for instance, $F=(y^2-x^2-1)(y^2-x^2-5)$ gives a closed curve which is two circles.)

Comment: @masiewpao the word for that kind of set is "bounded"

Comment: @DavidLui A finite interval is bounded but not necessarily closed in this sense. And then we have things like a figure 8 which is closed in this sense but not homeomorphic to the circle...

Comment: @KReiser That's a nice counter example. It seems a bit tricky to pin down the definition; I used 'closed' as I had seen it before but it wasn't explicitly defined. Could it make sense to say closed iff the curve has a parametrisation $\Gamma$ on $[a,b]$ s.t. $\Gamma (a) = \Gamma (b)$?